# problemas con el cin.ignore()

Tags: c++

Hola mi problema consiste en que debo hacer un listado de nombres y apellidos y luego guárdalos en un documento .txt , al momento de pedir los datos uso el cin.ignore() pero en el texto se me salta el primer campo y borra las primeras letras de los demás nombres, y si no uso el cin.ignore me da un problema en el for en el cual se me salta el primer ciclo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

void anadir(char nombre [50] , int i){
    ofstream archivo;
    archivo.open("lista nombres y apellidos.txt",ios::app);
     if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo"<<endl;
        exit(1);
     }
     archivo<<"Estudiante "<<i<<" : "<<nombre<<endl;
     archivo.close();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char nombres [50] ;
    int num,i;
    cout<<"Ingrese cuantos estudiantes tiene el curso"<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del estudiante "<<i<<endl;
        cin.getline(nombres,100,'\n');
         cin.ignore();
        anadir(nombres,i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

la llamada a `ignore` debe estar **antes** de la llamada a `getline`. El motivo es que el operador `>>` de `cin` **no elimina** el salto de línea, lo que hace que `getline` encuentre como primer caracter dicho salto de línea y deje de leer. Prueba así:

```
cin.ignore();
cin.getline(nombres,100,'\n');
```

Aunque ya que estás en programando en C++ tal vez prefieras usar `std::string` en vez de `char[]`:

```
std::string nombres;

// ...
cin.ignore();
std::getline(cin, nombres);
```